# Maven Dependencies are not installing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am using the maven embedded eclipse.
Tried :

1. Deleting the whole m2 repository.
2. Maven->Update Project.
3. Run as -> Maven Build
4. User settings file does not exist(Please don't tell me it has to something with this file)
   settings.Xml file

This file is only required if you are using a proxy and i am not

I have every dependency present in pom.xml file of my project but still eclipse is not able to import all these dependencies in the project

I have attached the photo below. Please help me to resolve my issue

[mvn dependency:tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ekE.png)

[Maven Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RWBr.png)

[POM.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB1bJ.png)

List of dependency present in pom file of my project

None of the methods mentioned above worked so please help me to solve this issue.
Is there anything related to maven or eclipse version ?

Comment: You haven't set up your proxy for maven, look at the other answer.

Comment: Settings.xml doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

When you execute mvn dependency:tree result shows an error related to "i cannot obtain some jar", it may be due to private reporitory.
If you are working with private repository, make sure you configure access in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
On another hand I see you are working with snapshots. If you are trying to bind projects you have in your local host machine, ensure you are executing `mvn install` (or better `mvn source:jar install`) sucessfully and your system's maven is pointing the same **.m2** path that refers Eclipse maven plugin

Comment: Nothing Happened

Answer (score 0):

It seems using the Spring framework Maven repository via HTTP instead of HTTP**S** causing this issue.

In your `pom.xml` file replace `http://maven.springframework.org` with `https://maven.springframework.org`.

Comment: You are such a genuis !! !I solved some of them by this but still two dependencies are missing.